# Python: sum dataframe rows with same datetime year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with two datetime columns and a third column with a numeric value. Here is an example:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-12-31 00:00:00 118433.0
2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-12-31 00:00:00 120087.0
2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-06-30 00:00:00 63831.0
2021-07-01 00:00:00 2021-12-31 00:00:00 63089.0
2022-01-01 00:00:00 2022-06-30 00:00:00 60753.0
2022-07-08 00:00:00 2022-11-30 00:00:00 9067.17
```

As you can see while 2019 and 2020 are full years, the other rows describe different time spans.

I need to sum all the numeric values pertaining to the same year to get something like:

```
2019 118422.0
2020 120087.0
2021 123842.0
2022 9067.0
```

The from-to dates on every row always fall in the same year.

Any given year does not have to be a full year.

I'd love to avoid simple iterations and learn a properly pythonic way of achieving this (list comprehension / vectorization).

Thank you

Comment: Whats happens if not full year?

Comment: Are there same years in both columns?

Comment: @mozway - so extreme closing? 2 different solutions together? :(

Comment: Let's be honest this is not a tricky question: `df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df[0]).dt.year).sum(numeric_only=True)` is it really benefiting the Q/A database to add such a poor case? There are dozens of groupby.sum on the site. I'm sure there is an exact duplicate somewhere

Comment: Plus, I'm sure that if **I** had answered it, you would have found a duplicate :p

Comment: @mozway - I still thinking if same year in both or not

Comment: @mozway - Absolutely not, not 100% dupe.

Comment: If this was the case, then the question is too unclear, also a reason to close.

Comment: @mozway - yop, it is unclear, agree. So ask in comments.

Comment: Sorry for not having specified better. a) As fas as I can see in the real data the two date columns are always in the same year. b) if not a full year, as in the example data and desired result for 2022, I just get the sum of whatever period falls in said year. Hope my wobbly english can be understood.

Comment: @RobertAlexander - OK, so working well `df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df[0]).dt.year).sum(numeric_only=True)`, right?

Comment: That gives a small error, but this works: print(df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df["dal"]).dt.year).sum(numeric_only=True)) thanks a lot